# Socket.io does not close the socket on demand (and does not allow my swift app to reconnect again to the node.js server)

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sockets, socket.io

I am playing around with `socket.io` library, I already implemented the server side (in `node.js`). I try to follow a very simple scenario:

1) user establishes connection

2) user connects to the room

3) user disconnects

4) user reconnects

I'm using ios app (written in `swift`) on a client side.

My server code is as follows:

```
io.on('connection', function(clientSocket){
    console.log('a user connected here');

    clientSocket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    clientSocket.on('connectUser', function(username){
        clientSocket.join(username);
        console.log('user ' + username + ' connected to the room.');
    });
```

Now in my client side I created a class responsible for handling all socket stuff:

```
class SocketIOManager: NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()
var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: serverURL)!, options: [.ForceNew(true)])

override init() {
    super.init()
}

func establishConnection() {
    socket.connect()
}


func closeConnection() {
    socket.disconnect()
}

func connectToServerWithNickname(nickname: String) {
    print("CONNECTING TO SOCKET SERVER \(nickname)")
    socket.emit("connectUser", nickname)
}
}
```

Now - further on - in my swift app (in `applicationDidBecomeActive`) I'm calling `establishConnection()` and then `SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.connectToServerWithNickname(username)`.

In my server console I see:

```
a user connected here
user 571fc6818451630f5becda9c connected to the room.
```

In my `appDelegate` I implemented this function:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.closeConnection()
    print("closing sockets")
}
```

so now when I put my app in the background I see `closing sockets` and in my server console I see `user disconnected`.

And now to the main problem - I want to reconnect user when he comes back to the app. Therefore I implemented this method:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    print("application is back to life")

    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
    SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.connectToServerWithNickname(username)

}
```

But now when I wake up the app from the background, in my server console I only see `a user connected here`. So this message:

```
user 571fc6818451630f5becda9c connected to the room.
```

is missing and I assume it's because my app is not reconnecting to the socket.

Now from what I've read, `socket.io` is really buggy and people recommend switching to other libraries, but I would like to use it anyway. I found this issue on github https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/251 and they recommend to use a specific parameter on client side. Following this plugin's page for swift https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift I found the specific flag:

```
case ForceNew(Bool) // Will a create a new engine for each connect. Useful if you find a bug in the engine related to reconnects
```

and that is why I'm constructing my socket on client side as:

```
var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: serverURL)!, options: [.ForceNew(true)])
```

but yeah, even in the official code of the `Socket.IO-Client-Swift` library there's a comment above the disconnect method:

```
/// Disconnects the socket. Only reconnect the same socket if you know what you're doing.
/// Will turn off automatic reconnects.
public func disconnect() {
    DefaultSocketLogger.Logger.log("Closing socket", type: logType)

    reconnects = false
    didDisconnect("Disconnect")
}
```

Does anyone know how could I handle that? I want to close the socket each time my app goes to the background and connect to it again when my app goes to the foreground. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add your code in applicationWillEnterForeground

SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()
SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.connectToServerWithNickname(username)